# Mod rewrite с параметрами как прописать правило?

Tags: apache, mod_rewrite

Мне нужно элементарное действие перекидывать с 
`site.ru/index.php?show=1&cat=2 на site.ru/index2.php?show=1&cat=2`

Обратите внимание просто перекидывать с этими же параметрами но на другой файл php.

Пробовал что то типа

```
RewriteRule ^index.php?show=([0-9]+)&cat=([0-9]+)$ index2.php?show=$1&cat=$2 [L]
```

Не работает, т.е. при любых действиях с параметром (если есть знак ?) переброс на index2 не работает. Так и остается на `index.php`.

Помогите, пожалуйста, как сделать?

Answer (score 2):

qsa == query string append
не нужно выскребать параметры руками. А если их больше станет? Пойдёте правила переписывать?)

Попробуйте так:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^index\.php /index2.php [QSA, L]
```

Comment: Все понял спасибо!!! Вот этот QSA мне и нужен был) извиняюсь за профанство)))

Comment: RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.xxx.ru$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://xxx.ru/$1 [R=301,L]

DirectoryIndex index.php
^index.php?db=([a-zA-Z0-9]+)&menu=([a-zA-Z0-9]+)&lang=([a-zA-Z0-9]+)$ index2.php?db=$1&menu=$2&lang=$3 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^$ index.php?show=1 [L]
RewriteRule ^page=([0-9]+)$ index.php?show=1&page=$1 [L]



Не работает(((( все остальные правила работают а это нет(

Comment: Ну вот же, я проверил работает с параметрами.

    RewriteRule ^index\.php$ /index2.php [R]

Comment: нет у меня задача другая ... если БЕЗ параметров типа xxx.com или xxx.com/index.php то у меня есть правило типа:
RewriteRule ^$ index.php?show=1 [L]
а если конкретно с этими параметрами то: 
с index.php?param1=1&param2=2 перекинуть на index_old.php с теми же параметрами... помогите плиз!!!

Answer (score 0):

В конце нужно указать флаг QSA
Т.е.

```
^index.php?show=([0-9]+)&cat=([0-9]+)$ index2.php?show=$1&cat=$2 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: А что это означает? скажите пожалуйста?

Comment: См ниже, тот вариант даже лучше подходит